# Subversion "show log" is offline

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i have a problem with mirroring SVN. I made a mirror copy running on Debian. Installed subversion and using svnsync i have mirrored all my svn repositories.
I run svnsync everyday with cron job. The problem is when i try to view log on my mirror server. I can browse it, i can open files in there, but if i "right click" and choose show log i got error:
"Want to go offline? there has been problem contacting the server"

This error is only appear if i choose how log. 
I can brows repository revisions and can open files from there.
Can someone help me here, please.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, the solution is to change the anon-access value to none in the svnserve.conf in the  svn server.

I have my SVN server in a linux suse. The repositories are in the /srv/svn/repos/ path, in this case I had the problem with my repo pe-svn-ea whose path is /srv/svn/repos/pe-svn-ea/. Inside this path there is a conf folder where there is the svnserve.conf.
After change this value I could perform the show log action without problems
[image]

Comment: It seems like a weird bug in svnserve. My svnserve.conf had the "anon-access" property mispelled. I had "non-access = none". I changed it to "anon-access = none" and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

My log kept appearing as offline (even after re-opening) until I hit the refresh button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

kcondezo's "anon-access" solution didn't help.

After an hour's try what finally worked was :

**Right click the folder >> "TortoiseSVN" >> "Update to revision" >>
click "Show log" button in the pop-up**

While the usual way [Right click >> "TortoiseSVN" >> "Show log"] gave problem, this button worked and strangely thereafter the usual way too started working !

Sounds stupid but worked for me!

This was TortoiseSVN 1.12.1 and its very likely a bug in TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

*@kcondezo*'s solution can't solve the problem. I found a stupid solution.

**Right click** ---->**TortoiseSVN**----->**Revision graph**.

The problem was be solved.

My svn client version is 1.13.1. Hope the solution can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this problem.
Right click -> TortoiseSVN -> Show log -> Refresh button (bottom left).
The problem was be solved.